# Overwriting CSS rules for specific areas

Tags: html, css, sass

In my code, I have `<p>` style at font-size 16px.
But, for a "card" I want to apply a font-size of 20px to any `<p>` text in there, without applying a slightly larger font-class to each `<p>` I may include.

So that any "card" class across the site, will have the same overwritten 20px, instead of 16px.

Comment: You can create another css class that has your overrides, eg `.big-font{ font-size: 20px !important; }` and then in your html element you add the class eg `<div class='card big-font'>Hello World</div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a "card"?  If it's just a div with class card:

```
.card {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

That will override the initial 16px if it is has higher specificity than the initial 16px.  Read up on CSS Specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I just reread the question. Ignore my comment above, this is the answer.

Comment: Ah ok great, thank you! I knew there was a "hierarchy" but couldn't recall the name to look up the rules for it. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using bootstrap class -> 'card'.

```
.card p
{
 font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

define above class in your stylesheet. It will work smoothly , it will apply the mentioned font size in every **p** tag you use inside a class 'card' anywhere on your page.

Good Luck.

Comment: Almost, I am using Bulma and one of their pre-made components is card and was the component I was trying to edit/understand. I have actually been doing just that, creating my own classes in a new file as to learn how they are created as well as how to edit them (without adding conflicts to existing classes)

Thanks for the reply, it helped very much!

Comment: @KJParker , I have edited the answer. This works fine. I feel this shall work smoothly without any special efforts. Thank You